# Do some dynamic time calculating events on several tags, jQuery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have several `p` tags that have same class but different title values.

And depending on each title, I want to do some time calculating event.

Here are my `p` tag examples.

```
<p class="timePTag" id="pId1" title="2017-07-09T17:50:58.528Z">Calculated timedelta 1</p>

<p class="timePTag" id="pId2" title="2017-07-10T17:50:58.528Z">Calculated timedelta 2</p>

<p class="timePTag" id="pId3" title="2017-07-12T17:50:58.528Z">Calculated timedelta 3</p>
```

In that, pId can be grow, like pId4, pId5 ... and each title attribute has different value.

What i want to calculate is timedelta_ time difference between `title` value and `now` time, which can be from `var now = new Date;`

I tried this,

```
setInterval(function() {
        var now = new Date;
        var title = $(".timePTag").attr("title");
        var sourcedate = new Date(title);
        var timestamp = Math.floor((now - sourcedate) /1000) + "Days";
        console.log(timestamp);
        $(".timePTag").text(timestamp);
}, 1000);
```

But it returned same things in all `p` tags.
I need dynamic timedelta result.

How can i do this?

My expecting result is like,

```
<p class="timePTag" id="pId1" title="2017-07-09T17:50:58.528Z">12days ago</p>

<p class="timePTag" id="pId2" title="2017-07-10T17:50:58.528Z">11days ago</p>

<p class="timePTag" id="pId3" title="2017-07-12T17:50:58.528Z">9days ago</p>
```

Comment: `(now - sourcedate) /1000)` will give you difference in `seconds` and not in `days`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate over the results in jquery, Otherwise you work on all elements at once.  Use the each function:
https://api.jquery.com/each/

```js
setInterval(function() {
  var now = new Date;
  $(".timePTag").each(function() {
    var title = $(this).attr("title");
        var sourcedate = new Date(title);
        var timestamp = Math.floor((now - sourcedate) /1000 / 60 / 60 / 24) + " Days";
        $(this).text(timestamp);
  });
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="timePTag" id="pId1" title="2017-07-09T17:50:58.528Z">Calculated timedelta 1</p>

<p class="timePTag" id="pId2" title="2017-07-10T17:50:58.528Z">Calculated timedelta 2</p>

<p class="timePTag" id="pId3" title="2017-07-12T17:50:58.528Z">Calculated timedelta 3</p>
```

Comment: `(now - sourcedate) /1000)` will give you difference in `seconds` and not in `days`

Comment: @KoushikChatterjee Good catch.  I updated the answer accordingly.